# Is there a valid way to demean a categorical variable?

Tags: probability

I have read about use of centering an explanatory variable in regression analysis on the mean (through demeaning) when there is presence of multicollinearity. I have applied this for a binary explanatory variable that takes only 0,1 values. Is there a valid way to demean an explanatory variable that is categorical?

Comment: Unless we use some categorical encoder (target, James-Stein, etc.) I don't think this makes a lot of sense (but those are usually centered to 0 anyway). That said, if you do it purely for numerical reasons just treat them like any other numerical predictor and demean them directly.

Comment: $0$ and $1$ are valid real numbers, along with all the rest, and can be scaled and translated in exactly the same fashion.  But multicollinearity rarely is cured by centering all the variables!

Answer (score 0):

No need for that. Pick the appropriate contrast coding. I've found that sum contrasts work nicely if you have any interactions. Otherwise, old-fashioned dummy/treatment contrasts work nicely. No need to get excessively fancy if your predictor is plain multinomial. However, recoding a single variable will do nothing for multicollinearity.